Changing Chapter Style whit horizontal lines
I was trying to change the chapter style in a LaTex file as in the below image, for that I was trying to manage the command titlesec but it was fruitless. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks
My try was this:
\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\bfseries\huge\titlerule[0.5pt]}{\filright\huge\thechapter.}{1ex}{\huge\filright #1}[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]



Welcome! Please provide the code for a small example document showing what you've tried and why it was 'fruitless'. Personally, all my interactions with titlesec have been fruitless, but others swear by it.

You want also to format the numberless version.
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{newtx}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\huge\bfseries\filright}
 {\hrulefill\mbox{\normalfont\sffamily\ \textsc{\MakeLowercase{\chaptername}} \thechapter}}
 {0pt}
 {}
 [\vspace{3pt}\titlerule]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
 {\huge\bfseries\filright}
 {\hrulefill}
 {0pt}
 {}
 [\vspace{3pt}\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Classical Results from Smooth Vector Field Theory}

\end{document}



Thank you very much!

Like this ?
In the titlesec documentation

section 3.4. Rules
example p.24

The code
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\Large}
  {}
  {0 ex}
  {\titleline{\titlerule \huge\MakeUppercase{~\chaptertitlename}~\thechapter}
  \vspace{2ex}%
  \filright\huge#1}
  [\vspace{2ex}%
  \titlerule]
\begin{document}
\chapter{Classical Results from Smooth Vector Fields Theory}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}


